# Contents not showing on CPropertyPageEx

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a program which uses Property Sheet Ex as the main program which holds several pages that user Property Page Ex. When i run the program, the first page shows fine, pages has only List Control on it and i have 2 pages, but when i click the tab to the next page, it is not showing anything and also when i click the first tab, i don't see the List Control.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CPageExposure, CPropertyPageEx)

CPageExposure::CPageExposure() : CPropertyPageEx(CPageExposure::IDD){}

CPageExposure::~CPageExposure()
{
}

void CPageExposure::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
 CPropertyPageEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
 DDX_Control(pDX,IDC_LIST2,m_list);
}

 BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPageExposure, CPropertyPageEx)
 ON_WM_SIZE()
 ON_WM_DESTROY()
 END_MESSAGE_MAP()

 BOOL CPageExposure::OnInitDialog()
 {
 CPropertyPageEx::OnInitDialog();

 CRect rc; int cx;
 GetClientRect(&rc);

 cx = (rc.Width()-30)/3;

 m_image.Create(1,20,ILC_COLOR,0,1);
 m_list.SetImageList(&m_image,LVSIL_SMALL);

 m_list.InsertColumn(0,"Time",LVCFMT_LEFT,cx);
 m_list.InsertColumn(1,"Login",LVCFMT_LEFT,cx);
 m_list.InsertColumn(2,"Request",LVCFMT_LEFT,cx);
 m_list.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES);

 return(TRUE);
 }
```

I hope you can help me with this..

Thanks...

Comment: When you debug it, does it enter into OnInitDialog function?

Comment: yes, i have removed some custom function for resizing and now it works.

Comment: Did you check if the correspondent dialog in the Resource Editor has the `Style` set to `Child`?